# conda install fails to find packages that are in specified channels

Tags: anaconda, conda, zsh, miniconda, blast

I am on a ARM Mac, and just installed miniconda.  However, it fails to install packages that are commonly used and available for the channels I've specified.  E.g.:

```
(orthofinder) ➜  ~ conda install -c bioconda blast
Channels:
 - bioconda
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - blast

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


(orthofinder) ➜  ~ conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
(orthofinder) ➜  ~ conda --version
conda 23.11.0
```

I have run `conda config --set offline false`

This package exists on the bioconda channel: https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blast.

However, running `search` with `-vvv` suggests that it's not finding blast there for some reason:

```
(orthofinder) ➜  ~ conda search -c bioconda blast -vvv
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_log_level(232): log_level set to 10
Loading channels: ...working... DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(316): package cache directory '/Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(799): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/57e79ec4.json. Timeout in 1243 sec
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/57e79ec4.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(799): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/2a957770.json. Timeout in 1243 sec
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/2a957770.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(799): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/a850f475.json. Timeout in 2179 sec
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/a850f475.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(799): Using cached repodata for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.json. Timeout in 2176 sec
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/09cdf8bf.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(808): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(122): Using CondaRepoInterface
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(1019): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(474): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(152):
>>GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Darwin/23.2.0 OSX/14.2.1 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> If-Modified-Since: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 00:22:18 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"ad12aa35631c7089749a7f6bb555f25b"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 59607
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 85892ec4298d1514-RIC
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://content.anaconda.com/
< Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:33:41 GMT
< ETag: "ad12aa35631c7089749a7f6bb555f25b"
< Expires: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:34:11 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 00:22:18 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=YZ9kc.hS8OEvaLCUrtH9qYrw2f18pLskOVoBUtDshjE-1708457621-1.0-AauagkL59w1soZkws8BCVQ4GoclpaNmVfZaEQ5Fp8PQ1SC9RvQnrarA76lFZ2/UmtzFiC56hVj2zJn9Lu5cQJ44=; path=/; expires=Tue, 20-Feb-24 20:03:41 GMT; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: 2wv5o900V/okI++jTBuXHSWBULaOHCLfnPwy+Wg6xUjSPTQUP7DbBocjhT5TkVVJ3VBR4J+/q0g=
< x-amz-request-id: 6ZK9R2SADD2V7T79
< x-amz-version-id: nbnGiL2q75HmUbSBxQlZakqIjZcmSTO0
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.087384


DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(831): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/9e99ffaf.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(808): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(122): Using CondaRepoInterface
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(474): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(152):
>>GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Darwin/23.2.0 OSX/14.2.1 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cf_bm=YZ9kc.hS8OEvaLCUrtH9qYrw2f18pLskOVoBUtDshjE-1708457621-1.0-AauagkL59w1soZkws8BCVQ4GoclpaNmVfZaEQ5Fp8PQ1SC9RvQnrarA76lFZ2/UmtzFiC56hVj2zJn9Lu5cQJ44=
> If-Modified-Since: Fri, 02 Feb 2024 09:56:06 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"b3f249351ca7c2f2c97c91c6fccefcb9"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1579153
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 85892ec4f9f61514-RIC
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://content.anaconda.com/
< Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:33:41 GMT
< ETag: "b3f249351ca7c2f2c97c91c6fccefcb9"
< Expires: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:34:11 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Feb 2024 09:56:06 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: T4EPpOaxNh9QfkFaspFDLwrbw+RwAFp2x5F+Ph7CJiMPIP2S8ql83LLqo1tRKEhkJMcyYI7pjLk=
< x-amz-request-id: NCWFSFB1TWWADWBD
< x-amz-version-id: 0QlhY9pA_FJcEZ._hgLjLuRHPt3StvSF
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.029263


DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(831): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/3e39a7aa.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(808): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(122): Using CondaRepoInterface
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(474): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(152):
>>GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Darwin/23.2.0 OSX/14.2.1 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cf_bm=YZ9kc.hS8OEvaLCUrtH9qYrw2f18pLskOVoBUtDshjE-1708457621-1.0-AauagkL59w1soZkws8BCVQ4GoclpaNmVfZaEQ5Fp8PQ1SC9RvQnrarA76lFZ2/UmtzFiC56hVj2zJn9Lu5cQJ44=
> If-Modified-Since: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:27:22 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1669187
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 85892ec56a201514-RIC
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://content.anaconda.com/
< Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:33:41 GMT
< ETag: "bd18071599942dd824e1ec40e9d10873"
< Expires: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:34:11 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:27:22 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: YQIhyvuVc9i1ilKKpOvNvETDZN/Y9tjK+nQNwn4AGj+pBsa+lzU+DWZLsc1W1ROeyEzel9qRrsE=
< x-amz-request-id: 6ZRSCF1PMZTGQT0P
< x-amz-version-id: qq74F8wZiM.BcRfcrAyp1UmHfwCjHyAg
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.027363


DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(831): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/8bd55712.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(808): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:__init__(122): Using CondaRepoInterface
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(474): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:repodata(152):
>>GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Darwin/23.2.0 OSX/14.2.1 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: __cf_bm=YZ9kc.hS8OEvaLCUrtH9qYrw2f18pLskOVoBUtDshjE-1708457621-1.0-AauagkL59w1soZkws8BCVQ4GoclpaNmVfZaEQ5Fp8PQ1SC9RvQnrarA76lFZ2/UmtzFiC56hVj2zJn9Lu5cQJ44=
> If-Modified-Since: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 20:24:09 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"5fb2c14e21bd4559f0cf025334a5e8d5"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 82958
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 85892ec59a331514-RIC
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://content.anaconda.com/
< Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:33:41 GMT
< ETag: "5fb2c14e21bd4559f0cf025334a5e8d5"
< Expires: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 19:34:11 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 20:24:09 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: HXFGbXj5wEC434IKR0TbXd0ze68JBdlWxkkWRm6URqgMmlg8e0hg9/ia1hMepn/zMszWe3APLVo=
< x-amz-request-id: VSH3G4DMPSMJ8RMY
< x-amz-version-id: 5Cdb6XXEtITjT9qkJTPedBm0u8gtbmH4
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.028719


DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:fetch_latest(831): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.gateways.repodata:read_cache(879): Loading raw json for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json at /Users/scott/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/4ea078d6.json
done
No match found for: blast. Search: *blast*
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
bio-embeddings-deepblast           0.1.0    pyhd8ed1ab_0  conda-forge
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.18.0          r351_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.20.0          r351_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.20.0          r361_1  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.22.0           r36_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.24.0           r40_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.25.1           r40_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.26.0           r40_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.26.0   r40hdfd78af_1  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.28.0   r41hdfd78af_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.30.0   r41hdfd78af_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.30.0   r41hdfd78af_1  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.33.0   r42hdfd78af_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.36.0   r43hdfd78af_0  bioconda
bioconductor-hicdatalymphoblast          1.38.0   r43hdfd78af_0  bioconda
blast-codes                      1.0      hd8ed1ab_0  conda-forge
blast-codes                      1.0      hd8ed1ab_1  conda-forge
blast-codes                      1.0      hd8ed1ab_2  conda-forge
blastbesties                   1.1.1            py_2  bioconda
blastbesties                   1.1.2    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
blastmining                    1.0.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
blastmining                    1.1.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
blastmining                    1.2.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
cblaster                       1.3.9    pyhb7b1952_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.11    pyhb7b1952_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.12    pyhb7b1952_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.15    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.16    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.17    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
cblaster                      1.3.18    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
crb-blast                      0.6.6               1  bioconda
crb-blast                      0.6.6               2  bioconda
crb-blast                      0.6.9      hdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.4    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.5    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.6    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.7    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.8    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.1.9    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                 0.1.10    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                 0.1.11    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.1    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.2    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.3    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.4    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.5    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.6    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  0.2.7    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  1.0.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  1.1.0 py311hdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  1.1.0 py311hdfd78af_1  bioconda
elastic-blast                  1.1.0    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
elastic-blast                  1.2.0  py39hdfd78af_0  bioconda
hpcblast                       1.0.2    pyhdfd78af_0  bioconda
parse_mito_blast                 1.0      hdfd78af_0  bioconda
parse_mito_blast               1.0.1      hdfd78af_0  bioconda
parse_mito_blast               1.0.1      hdfd78af_1  bioconda
parse_mito_blast               1.0.2      hdfd78af_0  bioconda
perl-bio-tools-run-remoteblast           1.7.3 pl5321hdfd78af_0  bioconda
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r36h142f84f_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r40h142f84f_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r40hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r41hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r41hc72bb7e_1  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.2   r42hc72bb7e_1  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.3   r41hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.3   r42hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.3   r42hc72bb7e_1  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.3   r43hc72bb7e_1  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.4   r42hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-blastula                     0.3.4   r43h6115d3f_0  pkgs/r
r-blastula                     0.3.4   r43hc72bb7e_0  conda-forge
r-neuroblastoma                  1.0   r36h6115d3f_0  pkgs/r
r-neuroblastoma                  1.0   r42h142f84f_0  pkgs/r
r-neuroblastoma             2023.9.3   r43h142f84f_0  pkgs/r
reparation_blast               1.0.7         pl526_0  bioconda
reparation_blast               1.0.8         pl526_0  bioconda
reparation_blast               1.0.9 pl5262hdfd78af_2  bioconda
reparation_blast               1.0.9         pl526_0  bioconda
reparation_blast               1.0.9         pl526_1  bioconda
reparation_blast               1.0.9 pl5321hdfd78af_3  bioconda
```

Any thoughts on how to debug or find the issue would be appreciated!

Comment: See duplicate. Also, I recommend bioinformaticians install Miniforge, not Miniconda. If you expect to frequently use Bioconda channel, consider using the **osx-64** installer so that emulation becomes the default rather than something you have to manually specify for each environment.